# str_replace() with associative array

Tags: php

You can use arrays with str_replace():

```
$array_from = array ('from1', 'from2'); 
$array_to = array ('to1', 'to2');

$text = str_replace ($array_from, $array_to, $text);
```

But what if you have associative array?

```
$array_from_to = array (
 'from1' => 'to1';
 'from2' => 'to2';
);
```

How can you use it with str_replace()?
Speed matters - array is big enough.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`$text = strtr($text, $array_from_to)`

By the way, that is still a one dimensional "array."

Comment: it is not perfect solution for stated problem (cause lengths should be the same), but it is ideal in my case. And speed is fast.

Comment: `strtr` works fine with replacement values that differ in length from the search value. The difference between it and `str_replace` is that `strtr` will only do one translation (the longest is matched first), which will be faster (but with different results). E.g., ['ab' => 'c', 'c' => 'd'] will translate 'ab' to 'c', while with str_replace it will become 'd'.

Comment: another thing is `strtr` is quite fast because the PHP directly uses the C version which is believed to be implemented using look up tables

Answer (score 38):

```
$array_from_to = array (
    'from1' => 'to1',
    'from2' => 'to2'
);

$text = str_replace(array_keys($array_from_to), $array_from_to, $text);
```

The `to` field will ignore the keys in your array. The key function here is `array_keys`.

Comment: Could $array_from_to be traversed in different order than what array_keys() return?

Answer (score 9):

```
$text='yadav+RAHUL(from2';

  $array_from_to = array('+' => 'Z1',
                         '-' => 'Z2',
                         '&' => 'Z3',
                         '&&' => 'Z4',
                         '||' => 'Z5',
                         '!' => 'Z6',
                         '(' => 'Z7',
                         ')' => 'Z8',
                         '[' => 'Z9',
                         ']' => 'Zx1',
                         '^' => 'Zx2',
                         '"' => 'Zx3',
                         '*' => 'Zx4',
                         '~' => 'Zx5',
                         '?' => 'Zx6',
                         ':' => 'Zx7',
                         "'" => 'Zx8');

  $text = strtr($text,$array_from_to);

   echo $text;

 //output is

yadavZ1RAHULZ7from2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$search = array('{user}', '{site}');
$replace = array('Qiao', 'stackoverflow');
$subject = 'Hello {user}, welcome to {site}.';

echo str_replace ($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Results in `Hello Qiao, welcome to stackoverflow.`.

```
$array_from_to = array (
    'from1' => 'to1',
    'from2' => 'to2'
);
```

This is not a two-dimensional array, it's an associative array.

Expanding on the first example, where we place the $search as the keys of the array, and the $replace as it's values, the code would look like this.

```
$searchAndReplace = array(
    '{user}' => 'Qiao',
    '{site}' => 'stackoverflow'
);

$search = array_keys($searchAndReplace);
$replace = array_value($searchAndReplace);
# Our subject is the same as our first example.

echo str_replace ($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Results in `Hello Qiao, welcome to stackoverflow.`.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in $array_from_to... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);
$text = str_replace($key, $values, $string);
```